# Spfx with Dataverse

Tags: spfx, dataverse

I have been developing SPFX with SharePoint lists as data source. Recently I come across dataverse for Power Apps.
My question is

1. How to connect spfx with Dataverse.
2. How to track version history in dataverse as we have in SharePoint list version history to track all changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can access dataverse in SPFx. You will require an enterprise app registration with delegated permission to access Dynamic CRM.

For app registration and  api permission refer the below Microsoft
Docs

- [App Registration for Accessing the Dataverse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory#create-an-application-registration)

For accessing the api through enterprise application follow the
below Microsoft Docs.

- [Request permissions to the enterprise API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi#request-permissions-to-the-enterprise-api)
- [Consume enterprise APIs secured with Azure AD in SharePoint
  Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi)

Comment: Could you use the **51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d** as the sample connecting via postman does? And if so what should be put into the webApiPermissionRequests?