# Help with SPFx and Dataverse

Tags: rest, spfx, spfx-webparts, httpcontext, dataverse

I'm trying to do CRUD functionality on a Dataverse table from an SPFx app. I keep getting the same error:

**To view the information on this page, ask a Global or SharePoint Administrator in your organization to go to the API management page in the new SharePoint admin center.**

I'm aware of the post found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300165/spfx-with-dataverse) and have been following the links in the post. What am I missing? I have run out of troubleshooting steps I know to try.

If it matters, I'm using the hosted workbench to test.

Answer (score 1):

One of the links in the post you linked is [Request permissions to the enterprise API](https://Request%20permissions%20to%20the%20enterprise%20API). This has two pieces, you make permission requests in the **config/package-solution.json** file of your SPFx project and you then grant those permission requests in the **API access** page of the SharePoint Admin Center (shown with the old name of the page, **API management**, in the second screen capture).

[image]

[image]

Based on the error message you included in your question, if would appear that you or your SharePoint administrator has not granted the permission requests made in your SPFx project.

If you have granted the necessary permission requests, there are two things you can try.

1. Discard the existing web part from the workbench by clicking the **Discard** option in the top-level menu and re-add it. If you still get the error try a hard refresh (CTRL + F5).
2. Test the web part in an actual SharePoint page rather than the workbench.

Comment: Started over and added the SPFx to my SharePoint site and then approved it. Still having 401 error. Could it be the url I'm using?

[https://org************.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/cr32c_testouts](https://org************.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/cr32c_testouts)